# How to silence webpack HMR console output

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-hmr

I have a simple webpack setup with `HotModuleReplacementPlugin()` added. I run webpack via it's NodeJS API.

```
compiler.watch(
    { stats: 'errors-only' },
    () => { console.log('Webpack is watching files.');
});
```

By specifying the stats option I am able to disable all webpack build outputs. But the HMR plugin outputs are still visible on the console like so:

[HMR] Updated modules:

[HMR]  - ./server/src/server.js

[HMR] Update applied.

Is there any way to disable this output as well?

Comment: Maybe helps: [webpack devserverclientloglevel](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverclientloglevel), [Stats](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/), [react-hot-loader issue 79](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/79)